# Nested regular expression strings

Tags: python, regex

I'm having trouble writing a regular expression for the following. I have a vector of literals (see RE_LIT) and I would like to find all the vectors in a line of text but I'm having difficulty writing the regular expression. Specifically I seem to have issues with the parenthesis acting as groups and not parenthesis.

```
RE_LABEL1 = r'[cvx]\d+(?![.]r)$'
RE_LABEL2 = r'v\d+\.r\d+'
RE_LABEL = r'(%s)|(%s)' % (RE_LABEL1, RE_LABEL2)
RE_LIT = r'!?%s' % RE_LABEL
RE_VEC = r'\[\s*(\s*%s\s*,?\s*)+\s*\]' % RE_LIT
```

Example string to match:

```
test = 'c1 = blah([v3,v4,v5.r1,!v6,v7,x8,v9,v10], [v1, v2], [x5.r1])'
```

Expected results:

```
> print re.findall(RE_VEC, test)
['[v3,v4,v5.r1,!v6,v7,x8,v9,v10]', '[v1, v2]']
```

Thank you ahead of time for your help.

Comment: *"I seem to have issues with the parenthesis acting as groups and not parenthesis"* - parentheses have meaning in regular expressions. If you want them to just be characters, *escape them* with a prefixed backslash: `\(`. Your example isn't a very useful test, as `r'\[[^]]+]'` would work fine...

Comment: Jonrsharpe: If I were to use this method how would I ensure that the entry's in the list are literals (RE_LIT) not just characters?

Comment: Yes parentheses have meaning in regular expressions but is there some mechanism that will act like parentheses normally does for nesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following fix:

```
import re
RE_LABEL1 = r'[cvx]\d+(?![.]r)'
RE_LABEL2 = r'v\d+\.r\d+'
RE_LABEL = r'%s|%s' % (RE_LABEL1, RE_LABEL2)
RE_LIT = r'\!?%s),?\s*' % RE_LABEL
RE_VEC = r'(?:(?:%s)+' % RE_LIT
test = '[v3,v4,v5.r1,!v6,v7,x8,v9,v10], [v1, v2]'
print re.findall(RE_VEC, test)
```

Output of an [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/9003sG):

```
['v3,v4,v5.r1,!v6,v7,x8,v9,v10', 'v1, v2']
```

Comment: Does this work for you or do you need another approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
RE_LABEL1 = r'[cvx]\d+(?=[ ,\]])'
RE_LABEL2 = r'v\d+\.r\d+(?=[ ,\]])'
RE_LABEL = r'%s|%s' % (RE_LABEL1, RE_LABEL2)
RE_LIT = r'\!?%s' % RE_LABEL
RE_VEC = r'\[\s*(?:(?:\s*%s\s*\s*),?)+\s*\]' % RE_LIT
test = '[v3,v4,v5.r1,!v6,v7,x8,v9,v10], [v1, v2], [v1, x2.r2]'
print re.findall(RE_VEC, test)
```

Thank you stribizhev for your help, it got me half of the way there. The above is the finial solution.